# How ng multi select dropdown work it form dirty

Tags: javascript, angular

I use a lib in npm [Angular Multiselect Dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown)
How I can hide `div` alert depend on form dirty or not. My problem is when I load page and my `selectedAuthors` is put into `ng multi select dropdown` this makes form dirty.

```
<div class="col-8">
    <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="editForm.dirty">
        <strong>Every thing not saved will be lost</strong>
    </div>
</div>
<form #editForm='ngForm' id='editForm' (ngSubmit)="updateBook()">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="book.title" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"
            aria-describedby="emailHelp" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">Authors</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div>
                <ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Choose Author'" [settings]="dropdownAuthorSettings"
                    [data]="listAuthors" [(ngModel)]="selectedAuthors"
                    name="selectedAuthors"
                    (onSelect)="onItemSelectAuthor($event)"
                    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAllAuthor($event)" (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelectAuthor($event)"
                    (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAllAuthor($event)">
                </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" [disabled]=!editForm.dirty>Edit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You can remove the whole `div` if you are not going to show it

Comment: Hi, I mean depend on form dirty or not to hide or show it

Comment: That's what your code does at the moment. Please clarify what you are having issues with (read our [ask] page and come back to [edit] your question)